# Why does GRUB stall on a system that has only BIOS support with no UEFI?

Tags: ubuntu, grub, kubuntu, lubuntu

I have several old laptops that only support BIOS or Legacy mode. They do not have support for EFI/UEFI. The laptops all have a 64-bit CPU. I have attempted to create a bootable USB with `dd`, `cat` as well as the latest versions of tools such as [Rufus](https://rufus.ie), [UnetBootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/) and [balenaEtcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/).

I've tried several desktop flavors of [Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/) - [Ubuntu Budgie](https://ubuntubudgie.org/), [Kubuntu](https://kubuntu.org/) and [Lubuntu](https://lubuntu.me/). The hashes of the downloaded ISOs match. To rule out USB flash drive failures or issue, I have used different USB flash drives. Similarly, I have plugged the USB flash drives into different USB ports.

The `dd` command to create the bootable USB is `dd if=canonical.iso of=/dev/sdX bs=256k;sync`. The `cat` command is `cat canonical.iso > /dev/sdX;sync`

The laptop boots successfully, gets past the vendor splash image/screen e.g. HP and stops at `Welcome to GRUB!`. There are no other messages and it doesn't progress any further. Oddly, following the exactly the same steps with Ubuntu, it loads successfully.

Ubuntu 20.04.4 loads but none of the latest versions of the other flavors do.

**Update**

```
Laptop
HP Pavilion dv6-6137tx
CPU
Intel Core i7-2630QM
Graphics 
Device-1: Intel 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics driver: i915 v: kernel 
Device-2: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Whistler [Radeon HD 6730M/6770M/7690M XT] driver: radeon v: kernel
```

Comment: if you press enter or down arrow & then enter does it do anything? What video card/chip? What brand/model system? HPs with BIOS usually worked, but HP's UEFI often required some work arounds. Do you have latest BIOS from HP, even if older system and update is also older?

Comment: @oldfred - There's no change with hitting the arrow keys. I've updated the question with additional information on the type of laptop, CPU and graphics. Yes, it has the latest version of firmware.

Comment: If an I7 then it is UEFI, but often those early UEFI did have various issues. You have two video modes which may be a setting in UEFI to use internal (chip) or video chip. Not sure how that all works. Depending on amount of RAM, a lighter weight flavor may work better. So would continue with those flavors over full Ubuntu. Does this have Optane or Intel RST? https://askubuntu.com/questions/870453/live-boot-usb-install-of-16-04-fails-on-hp-pavilion-23 I also found this in my notes: Some HP will not boot a flash drive that is gpt partitioned. Some only boot from the USB2 port not USB3 ports.

Comment: @oldfred, in further testing it appears to be a GRUB2 issue. I've raised a bug report with Canonical - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1968147